# Passing array and int arguments of function to new thread

Tags: arrays, c, multithreading

I am attempting to pass an  2d array and index value which read from the keyboard as an arguments to a function using pthread_create, is this possible? I have an array of integers and I want to shift all rows of 4x4 2d array with  first k elements of each row with **2 threads**.

```
First thread shift row0 and row 1
```

```
Second thread shift row2 and row3
```

I read k from the keyboard so I pass it argument to a function
Here is my code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUMTHREADS 2
#define N 4
pthread_mutex_t myMutex;
int k;
int number = 0;

void shiftArray(int mat[N][N], int k)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&myMutex);
    int j = 0;
    number += N / 2;
    while (j < number)
    {

        // Print elements from index k
        for (int i = k; i < N; i++)
            printf("%d", mat[j][i]);

        // Print elements before index k
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
            printf("%d", mat[j][i]);

        printf("\n");
        j++;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&myMutex);
    pthread_exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t threads[NUMTHREADS];

    printf("please enter k value: ");
    scanf("%d", &k);
    printf("k = %d\n", k);

    int mat[N][N] = {{1, 2, 3, 4},
                     {5, 6, 7, 8},
                     {9, 10, 11, 12},
                     {13, 14, 15, 16}};

    pthread_mutex_init(&myMutex, NULL);

    for (int i = 0; i < NUMTHREADS; i++)
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, shiftArray, mat);

    for (int i = 0; i < NUMTHREADS; i++)
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&myMutex);

    return 0;
}
```

I couldn't pass both array and k value as an arguments into **pthread_create** and I got weird result. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass multiple arguments to a thread function.

You can however create a structure with multiple values, and pass a pointer to a structure object.

Note that if you want each thread to have different values from each other, then you need different structure object, one per thread. Like for example an array of `NUMTHREADS` structure object (in your case).

---

There are some other problems with your code, like you're not doing any work in parallel. Your threads are serial (in an unspecified order) because of the mutex you lock for the full duration of the thread function.

If the threads work only on their own small and unique part of the matrix `mat`, then you don't need the mutex since there's no sharing between the threads. Or if the threads only read data from the matrix and never write to it, then you don't need a mutex either.

Otherwise keep locks to the smallest possible part needed.